# Bug with passing parameters in ExtReact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In this part of the code passing the properties is fine and they are rendered once on the page:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        idOfPortletLocation: props.portletlocationid
    };
}

render() { 



    const text = (
        <div>
            {this.props.text.description}
            {this.state.idOfPortletLocation}
        </div>
    );
```

....

as you see from the screenshot:

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9pcj.png)

But this part of the code does not recognize property idOfPortletLocation:

```js
<Container padding={10} className="containerOfPanel"  flex = {1}/*style={{display: 'inline-block', position: 'absolute'}}*/> 
    <Panel 
     ref={panel => this.panel = panel}
     title= {this.props.text.title} 
     /*height= {this.props.height}*/
     /*minHeight = {this.props.height}*/

     tools={[ 
      {type: 'minimize', handler: this.toolHandler},
      {type: 'maximize', handler: (e) => this.toolHandler(e, this.state.idOfPortletLocation) }, 
      {type: 'close', handler: this.toolHandler }
     ]}
     resizable={{
      edges: "all", 
     }} 
     bodyPadding={10}
    >
     {text} 
    </Panel>
   </Container>
```

AND:

```
toolHandler(owner, tool, idOfPortletLocation) { 

    console.log(tool.config.type);
    console.log(idOfPortletLocation); /* Here it is not recognized */

    if(tool.config.type.valueOf() == "close"){
        console.log("passed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handler: (e) => this.toolHandler(e, this.state.idOfPortletLocation) 
//here you are passing only two arguments and idOfPorletLocation as second argument
//but in toolHandler there are three arguments and idOfPorletLocation as third argument but was passed as second argument

so correct function should be -

```
toolHandler(tool, idOfPortletLocation) { 

console.log(tool.config.type);
console.log(idOfPortletLocation); /* Here it is now recognized */

if(tool.config.type.valueOf() == "close"){
    console.log("passed");
}
```

Let me know if it works for you)

Comment: Yes it worked for me well I have added two parameters instead of three in toolHandler and I passed string for every type of tool and I can recognize it now well...